# How to close a file using shell script

Tags: c, shell

I need to open and close a file using shell script.

myshell.sh

```
vi adc.c
```

when i execute myshell.sh, it opens a file.

I need to close that file using shell script.

what command should i include in myshell.sh

Comment: Why do you need `vi` (an interactive application) at all in your script? What is your use case? Do you simply want to display the file contents?

Comment: i want to create a file using shell script.when i did it using 'vi' a file is created but i need to manually do esc+wq

Comment: But do you require that the user can interactively edit the file? If you only want to create the file, there are much simpler options in shell scripts

Comment: `vi` doesn't open the file it is editing. It's opened/closed at every savings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a file using shell script. When i did it using 'vi' a file is created but i need to manually do esc+wq

`vi` is an interactive file editor. It allows you to open/create a file, edit the file by user interaction, and finally save the file and quit (by `ESC-wq`). You can do this in a shell script (some applications do this to let the user edit text), but if you simply want to create a file with some contents in batch mode, without user interaction, use something like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "My contents" > /path/to/local/adc.c
cat /path/to/local/part-r-00000 >> /path/to/local/adc.c
```

The first line creates an empty file `adc.c`, the second line *appends* the contents of `part-r-00000` to the file.

There is no need to "create" the file first. This is done automatically by the shell. You might want to go through [Bash: All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) (there are similar pages for other shells).

Comment: ok , but see this. I need to do cat /path/to/local/part-r-00000> /path/to/local/adc.c so i should need to create adc.c

Comment: No. `>` automatically creates the file. Try it out.

Comment: thanks.ys it automatically creates a file.so when i run for the second time ,then the same file will get updated right.

Comment: Yes. Depending on the redirection you use (`>` or `>>`), the file contents is deleted first **or** the data is appended to the file

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using vi, try using touch ?

```
touch /opt/adc.c
```

Touch is an easiest way to create new and empty files. It is also used to Update the time-stamp. Then update the file contents.

```
echo "Your File contents" > /opt/adc.c
```

In this case, you will not need to "***Close***" your file.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly clear what you mean by "close" in this context.

Normally, open and close are low-level file system operations; you open a file, do the I/O you want by reading or writing, then close it when you're done.

It's not very likely that vi will leave the named file really, physically, open when you invoke it like you show. It's more likely to open the file, read its contents, and then close it. The file will be re-opened for writing when you tell vi to save the new content to disk, but it won't stay open between saves. At least I wouldn't assume so, but I'm no vi user.

What would you expect vi to do when you externally "close" the file?

Comment: this file will be used to write my hadoop result.so i should first create that file.later the data will be written into that

Comment: You do not need to "create" the file in this case. This is done automatically when you start writing into the file through redirections in your shell script.